# BodyParser to return Result based on request body

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to implement a BodyParser which parses and *validates* `request.body`, it's based on `parse.json` and currently looks like this:

```
def parseModel[A](implicit reads: Reads[A]): BodyParser[JsResult[A]] =
  parse.json.map(_.validate[A])
```

The problem is it is currently of type `BodyParser[JsResult[A]]` while I want it to be of type `BodyParser[A]`. In case of `JsError` I want it basically to return `400 Bad Request` with validation errors.

In [Play API docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParser) I can't find a method which allows me to inspect result of previous body parser and return a result or continue to a controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `BodyParser`, after parsing the body, produces an `Either[SimpleResult, A]`, where `SimpleResult` is an error result that should be returned immediately instead of processing the action.  The convenience methods on `BodyParser` don't let you do this, so instead, create a new body parser that delegates to the JSON body parser:

```
def validateJson[A](implicit reads: Reads[A]) = new BodyParser[A] {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = parse.json(request).map(_.right.flatMap { json =>
    json.validate[A].asEither.left.map(e => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(e)))
  })
}
```

You can see here that we're mapping the result of the parse, and then taking the `right` value (a successful parse, will be `JsValue`), and calling `flatMap` on it.  Our `flatMap` method converts the `JsResult` from `validate` to an `Either[JsError, A]`, so we're halfway there with `A`, after that we `map` the left `JsError` to `SimpleResult`, and we're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've implemented the desired behaviour via a method which produces an `Action`:

```
def validateJson[A](implicit reads: Reads[A]) =
  parse.json.map(_.validate[A])


def ModelAction[A](action: A => Result)(implicit r: Reads[A]) =
  Action(validateJson[A]) { request =>
    request.body match {
      case JsSuccess(model, _) => action(model)
      case JsError(e) => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(e))
    }
  }
```

I can use it like this:

```
def create = ModelAction[MyModel] { model =>
  ???
}
```

I'm still interested if it's possible to do the same with `BodyParser` and if I need to do so or it's better as it is now?